# Visual Studio Git - Support for Credential Helper

Tags: git, visual-studio, credentials

I have a Git repository that uses a custom credential helper in the .gitconfig file (to provide a custom set of credentials based on the current user).  This works fine when using Git/SourceTree and the like, but fails when using the built-in Git for Visual Studio 2015.

I was wondering if anyone knew if Visual Studio used/respected the credential helpers in the .gitconfig or whether I'm doing something else wrong.  Perhaps it does and it uses a different .gitconfig file that I can't see?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you done the good settings/configuration, like it says [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx#VersionControl)? I have not installed it yet... :(

Comment: Yup, I have configured it as much as it allows.  No luck unfortunately.